# Clustering a sequence with time stamps (a time series data of two events)

Tags: matlab, time-series, cluster-analysis

Have been exploring different options for clustering a time series data that is of the type :

two different events - say 1,2

events      time(nanos)

1. 1       1e3
2. 1       6e3
3. 1       8e3
4. 2       12e3
5. 1       54e3
6. 1       58e3
7. 1       62e3
8. 1       67e3
9. 1       70e3
10. 1       75e3
11. 2       103e3
12. 2       108e3
13. 2       114e3
14. etc     etc

ie., the times are stochastic (exponentially distributed) and either event 1 or event 2 is recorded. the recordings are in nanoseconds. The data set is large, going upto 15-20 mts, and with millions of points

The events are correlated and thus a bunch of 2s or 1s could happen. For eg., There will be small pieces (1 millisecond long pieces having 100-200 events of both types). Some cases, there will be a series of just one event type happening which needs to be discarded. 
And most of the time, just single or few events are recorded & this is just noise (>80% of the data).

This is clearly a time series data, with event type information.

I would like to apply a clustering methodology to identify the meaningful small pieces. I'm using Matlab and have tried to look into options such as DBSCAN, k-means (not useful since I don't know the number of clusters apriori) etc.,

(the recording times themselves could be taken as a 'distance' since these are sequential chunks. ie., dist(x1,x2) = abs( x2(2) - x1(2) )  if x is (event, time) ; 
also, a meaningful sequence of events happening at say time = 10.2 to 10.23 seconds, has no relationship to any other piece. ie., the clustering is done only to "identify" the short pieces  (expected to be few 10000s out of the whole dataset)

Any help would be appreciated !  Thanks.

Comment: Have you looked into `clusterdata()`?

Comment: yes. out of memory problems because of huge data set,though I could iterate smaller lengths). But am not sure how to extract just the relevant pieces I want.

Comment: Have you tried the savememory option? Also, please elaborate on 'meaningful sequence of events'; from the comments to Hugh's answer, it seems that you discriminate only by timestamps, which already reduces the dimensionality of the problem, i.e. cluster time only.

Comment: Yes, for the whole set, even with the savememory option it goes out of memory (understandably so). It's not the major issue since I can analyze shorter pieces of long time series.

Comment: Ideally, definition of meaningful pieces includes both the time stamps & the event types. a good piece would have a ratio of both the events & will have the events happening within short intervals. The recording has lots of noise that needs to be filtered. Some observations about noise are: there could be traces where, majority only 1 event happens that too in quick intervals (like good data). Such noisy traces could be within a good trace as well & could be just few points too(eg,10 noisy pts in a good trace of 200 pts). Hence the idea of clustering the event types that occur close in time.

Answer (score 1):

What about taking the difference between time points and determining either empirically or statistically a threshold below which the events are "connected"?

```
dtimes=diff(nanotimes);
THRESH=100; % completely made up - will depend on your data
current_cluster=1;
assign_clusters=zeros(size(nanotimes));
assign_clusters(1)=current_cluster;
for (v=1:length(dtimes))
    if (dtimes(v)>THRESH)
        current_cluster=current_cluster+1;
    end
    assign_clusters(1+v)=current_cluster;
end

for v=1:current_cluster
    indices=find(assign_clusters==v);
    if (~any(events(indices)==1)) || ...
        all(events(indices)==1) || ...
        (nanotimes(indices(end))-nanotimes(indices(1)) < TIMETHRESH)

        assign_clusters(indices)=-1; 

    end
end
```

Comment: Thanks Hugh, this is in fact what I have been doing.Sorry not to have mentioned it. Since meaningful events happen within shorter intervals (threshold # of events within a time period & with dtimes<cutoffvalue) than most of the noise. But, there also cases where there could be events with rapid succession but not meaningful that are also picked up by this method. Hence, the idea/need for clustering.

Comment: How do you define meaningful? That is the root of the issue!

Comment: Pieces that have a mixture of both events, not too long or short (~300us - 1ms).

Comment: OK see edit above - if there are no event values in the cluster equal to 1, or if all event values in the cluster are equal to 1, or if the last minus first time point in the cluster is less than a time threshold, set the clustered values to -1. Any cluster values over zero are meaningful by your criteria. You should be able to add a second "too long" time threshold without too much trouble based on the above.

Comment: Thanks Hugh, this makes a sensible solution capturing well the multiple steps I have been following to extract the meaningful pieces out. Will test it further. Could you also think of application of any of the clustering algorithms to approach this.

Comment: I'm not sure that the inbuilt cluster algorithms are designed for time-series / section analysis like this. Maybe using clusterdata with correlation as its method? It's not a clustering but a classification problem, really, as you only have "interesting" and "not interesting" with some specific constraints, and it is not each points you wish to classify, but groups of points. I think to prepare your data for your clustering algorithm you will be doing more work than the above code.

Comment: Hugh, just edited the above piece that had the conditional `indices=find(assign_clusters==v);` as `indices=find(assign_clusters==current_cluster)`

Answer (score 0):

You probably are looking in the wrong domain.

Cluster analysis is meant for **multidimensional data**, but you have just one true dimension, time.

You really should look at classic **statistical methods** for series, such as kernel density estimation, natural breaks optimization and such things.

For example, you could estimate the density of events 1 and event 2 using a **kernel density estimator**, then split the data set whenever the density of event 1 or event 2 becomes higher than the other by a certain threshold. It's actually quite straightforward, once you compute the KDE curves.

Comment: Thanks for the reference to statistical methods like KDE. Have come across it but  haven't used before. How effective will be than the simple 'time' based filtering above? Do you have any particular code example.

Comment: KDE is much more robust, and widely accepted, with a wealth of theory backing it.